# Dependent clause at the beginning of a sentence which modifies the predicate

Tags: terminology, parts-of-speech, adverbial-phrases

I’m looking for a term that describes the dependent clause at the beginning of a sentence that modifies the predicate (not sure if I’m describing this accurately). For example, in the sentence “With a lot of force, John pushed over the boulder,” I want to describe the “with a lot of force” portion. Another example: “Reluctantly, Bob gave John his lunch.” -> “Reluctantly”

My English teacher called this “companion action”, but after searching this term up, it seems like my teacher made up this term? I would greatly appreciate any clarification on this.

Comment: Looks like a [fronted adverbial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase#Adverbial_fronting) to me.

Comment: "With a lot of force" isn't a clause because it has no subject and no verb. It's an adverbial phrase, as @ColinFine has pointed out. I've never heard the term "companion action", and it's not a good term because neither of your example phrases is an action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a fronted phrase describing a state of mind a "fronted adverbial"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193710/is-a-fronted-phrase-describing-a-state-of-mind-a-fronted-adverbial) Also [Is there a rule for using adverbial clauses/phrases directly after conjunctions?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299894/is-there-a-rule-for-using-adverbial-clauses-phrases-directly-after-conjunctions)

Comment: They are both adjuncts consisting of a preposition phrase and an adverb phrase respectively. But they are not modifiers -- they are supplements, loosely attached expressions set off by intonation and punctuation presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.